# Can time() and few additional overload the server while displaying/calculating for top 100 users page?

Tags: php, nginx

So, I need to know if somehow the time() + 10800 and etc can overload a page if its loading data separately for 100 users? It's a ranking page where I am calculating the online time. It's selecting top 100, so if a lot of users check this page, can the following code overload it by the calculation the time separately for each user or it should be fine? I meant that these array values will be included in the user ranking page which contains top 100 users. so if they are ONLINE, it will do some calculation otherwise nope. **I ask basically if for example 50-60 are online, and if a lot of people try to view the user ranking (accessing the page) - it will do a lot of calculation, can this be a concern or it should be fine mostly? Server is running on nginx, MSSQL Server 2005 (just to mention it in case :))**

```
$replace = array
(
            'total_time'    => $data['Status'] == offline ? $this->secondsToTime(intval($data['TotalTime'])) : $this->secondsToTime(intval($data['TotalTime']) + (time() + 10800) - intval($data['LoginDT'])),
            'login_time'    => $data['Status'] == offline ? "N/A" : $this->secondsToTimeCurr(time() + 10800 - intval($data['LoginDT'])));
    .....................
```

Comment: There are too many variables (sever config, db cache, php cache etc) to give a definitive answer. You could wrap you function in $start = microtime(); code here $end = microtime(); and see what timing it actually takes.

Comment: I understand just overall by looking at it AND especially this: `(time() + 10800) - intval($data['LoginDT'])` can it overload the server because of these calculations? I believe it cannot but let me know what you think please?